# C++Primer 5th in p.343. that no match for c.insert(p,b,e)

Tags: c++, string, c++11

There is a problem that I can't understand.
Look the picture as follows:

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


// use the string rep to replace the value in string str

void Replace(string& str,const char& value,const string& rep)

{

    auto iter = str.begin();

    while(iter != str.end())
    {
        if(*iter == value)

        {
            iter = str.erase(iter);

            iter = str.insert(iter,rep.begin(),rep.end());

            iter += rep.size();

            continue;

        }

        ++iter;

    }

}

int main()

{

    string str = "Welcome to Stack Overflow";

    Replace(str,' ',"****");

    cout<<str<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

GCC 4.9(C++11)

Compiler messages:

```
main.cpp: In function 'void Replace(std::string&, const char&, const string&)':
main.cpp:14:18: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >' and 'void')
         iter = str.insert(iter,rep.begin(),rep.end());
```

but..I can't find the function drawed above the picture in cppreference.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert

so:
Please tell me, Did I say wrong??
and then how I to fit it ?

Comment: How are you compiling?  Do you have C++11 turned on?

Comment: yes, in addition to run it in my compiler(CodeBlock 16.1 compiled by C++11).  I try it in the cppreference sites, using the GCC 4.9(C++11).

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e09faf7d4f01d4e).  It really looks like you do not have C++11 turned on since the function you are calling returns `void` before C++11 and a `iterator` in C++11 and above.

Comment: I can't find the this corresponding function insert return a iterator in C++11.  how do you find it? where?   I am sure that I already have used the C++11 complier whichI try it several times. Did you run it without error ??

Comment: It is listed in the link to cppreference in your question.  see overload 8.  It was `void insert( iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );` before C++11 and now it is `iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );`

Comment: Yes,you are right. thx

Comment: Did you get it working then?

Comment: No, just find that function before I think this function the first parameter is the index position not the iterator.  ,  iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );   what's more, but  it seem like strange. I already used C++11(-std = c++11) in CodeBlock compiler. and then I run it in my command in windows  also uses gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC).  all occurs ths same error.

Comment: do you know what cause??

Comment: I'm not sure.  It compiles fine for me so something is not right with your settings and the error message makes it look like it is not actually compiling with C++11.

Comment: Oh,yeah. my brother. It finally worked. I reinstall the gcc version 5.3.0 replace previous compiler.

Comment: Great.  I'm going to close this unless you just want to delete it

Comment: I delete it , it will be no worth to others, I think.  thx